# Update value in array with value of same index from another array

Tags: php, arrays

Given array like this:

```
$products = array([0] => Apple, [1] => Orange, [2] => Orange, [3] => Strawberry, [4] => Orange, [5] => Mango, [6] => Orange, [7] => Strawberry, [8] => Orange, [9] => Orange, [10] => Orange);
```

I need to count number of similar values and receive array where each unique value will appear once along with the count of its occurrences from original array.
For example the new array should look like this:

```
$new_products = array([0] => "Apple 1", [1] => "Orange 7", [2] => "Strawberry 2", [3] => "Mango 1");
```

Using functions below I can receive 2 arrays:

```
array_keys(array_count_values($products))); // Return array of unique values
array_values(array_count_values($products))); // Return array with count for each unique values
```

Will return:

```
Array ( [0] => Apple 1 [1] => Orange [2] => Strawberry  [3] => Mango )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 7 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 )
```

I cant find a way to merge the values so I get the array that looks like $new_products array in my example.

Comment: $result = array_map(function ($i1, $i2) { return $i1. ' ' . $i2; }, $ar_keys, $ar_counts);

Comment: hi, @Uchiha ! hundred years have not seen :)

Comment: @Uchiha, sometimes it's so nice to read in my native language :)

Comment: @splash58 Yep thats great somewhat active on SO

Comment: HI @splash58 can you please explain you answer? as I understand $ar_keys, $ar_counts are arrays resulted from my 2 functions. Tried this but receive nothing

Comment: @Sergio look there - https://eval.in/547943

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate `array_count_values` with `foreach`.

```
$new_products = [];
foreach (array_count_values($products) as $name => $count) {
  $new_products[] = $name. ' '. $count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
<?php

$products = array(
    0 => 'Apple', 
    1 => 'Orange', 
    2 => 'Orange', 
    3 => 'Strawberry', 
    4 => 'Orange', 
    5 => 'Mango', 
    6 => 'Orange', 
    7 => 'Strawberry', 
    8 => 'Orange', 
    9 => 'Orange', 
    10 => 'Orange'
);

function getNamesWithCountArray($array)
{
    $result = array();
    $countedValues = array_count_values($array);

    foreach($countedValues as $key => $value)
        $result[] = $key . ' ' . $value;

    return $result;
}

$new_products = getNamesWithCountArray($products);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_products);
```

Result of `print_r($new_products);` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple 1
    [1] => Orange 7
    [2] => Strawberry 2
    [3] => Mango 1
)
```